# C# How to make ArrayPool to return exact size array?

Tags: c#

`ArrayPool<byte>` in .netstandard20 has method `Rent(int minLength)` which return `byte[]` which will be at least `minLength` in size, but can be larger. I want to get `byte[]` of exact size for some legacy crypto providers which only accepts `byte[]` of particular sizes (such as 256, 512, etc) in my streaming framework (meaning, it will be very memory/io intensive, where those arrays can live up to gen2 which will bloat memory). Obviously, I can't go with `Span`/`ArraySegment`/etc because their method signature is not supporting these.

How I can retrieve `byte[]` from larger one? I thought about marshalling/mapping same memory section but don't know if it is possible.

**PS:**

Im fine with unsafe code, because I still dispose them correctly, I just need intermediate container for blocks of data and want to utilize unified approach which ArrayPool provides (don't want to write my own).

**Update:**

With help of *@GoodNightNerdPride* I came up with this fancy helper:

```
public static class ArrayPoolHelper
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This method will return disposable object which contain desired size T[] buffer.
    /// Works with any pool which supports desired size.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="pool">Array pool to use</param>
    /// <param name="size">Desired size</param>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <returns>Disposable rented array</returns>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException"></exception>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentOutOfRangeException"></exception>
    public static IRentedArray<T> RentExact<T>(ArrayPool<T> pool, int size)
    {
        if (pool == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(pool));
        if (size <= 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(size));
        }

        var rented = pool.Rent(size);
        var originalSize = UnsafeChangeLength(rented, (uint)size);
        return new RentedArray<T>(rented, originalSize, pool);
    }

    private static uint UnsafeChangeLength<T>(T[] array, uint newLength)
    {
        if (array.Length == newLength)
            return newLength;
        
        var unsafeRented = Unsafe.As<RawArrayData>(array);
        var originalLength = unsafeRented.Length;
        unsafeRented.Length = newLength;
        return originalLength;
    }

    private sealed class RentedArray<T> : IRentedArray<T>
    {
        private readonly uint _originalSize;
        private readonly ArrayPool<T> _pool;
        private readonly T[] _original;
        private bool _disposed;
        public T[] Data => _disposed ? throw new ObjectDisposedException(ToString()) : _original;

        public RentedArray(T[] original, uint originalSize, ArrayPool<T> pool)
        {
            _originalSize = originalSize;
            _pool = pool;
            _original = original;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (_disposed)
                return;
            UnsafeChangeLength(_original, _originalSize);
            _pool.Return(_original, true);
            _disposed = true;
        }
    }

    private sealed class RawArrayData {
        public uint Length;
    }
}
```

it will return disposable object which contain desired size buffer (kinda, it just makes it so it is desired, in reality it can be any buffer from selected pool):

```
using var rented = ArrayPoolHelper.RentExact(pool, 123);
Assert.AreEqual(rented.Data.Length, 123);
```

**Update 2:**

Method above will throw CLR errors on parallel invokations....so no, its not wise to change length.

Comment: Nothing that a `Dictionary<int, byte[]>` can't pool.

Comment: @HansPassant I don't want to rely on self-crafted ArrayPool. Considering how much effort/magic gone in default one (try to decompile it and you will see).

Comment: Look at the [default](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Buffers/ConfigurableArrayPool.cs,025f013308cf855c) and decide yourself. Its not magic.

Comment: @Ralf I thought about this one - https://github.com/dotnet/corert/blob/master/src/System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/Buffers/TlsOverPerCoreLockedStacksArrayPool.cs, also it limits how user can specify array pools.

Comment: It is *because* of the effort that they considered adding ArrayPool to the framework.  You've got the trivial case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well here's a dirty trick based on how `Array.Length` is implemented:

```cs
public abstract class Array : ... 
{
    public int Length => checked((int)Unsafe.As<RawArrayData>(this).Length);
    // ...
}
```

`RawArrayData` is an internal type, but you could just recreate it in your code to do the same:

```cs
public class RawArrayData {
    public uint Length;
    public uint Padding;
    public byte Data;
}
```

Then unsafely cast to `RawArrayData` and set `Length` to the desired value:

```cs
var xs = new byte[3];
Debug.Assert(xs.Length == 3);
var ys = Unsafe.As<RawArrayData>(xs);
ys.Length = 2;
Debug.Assert(xs.Length == 2);
```

Enumerating `xs` will then only return the first two items.

Don't forget to set it back after that crypto lib is finished though or the pool manager might get a tad confused...

Comment: Thanks! I will try it. Yeah, those thing are short lived and disposed correctly, so there should not be any problems.

Comment: @eocron What I mean is even though the pool manager created/re-used an array of size length 3, it will suddenly appear as an array of length 2 to it after you did this. This could lead to a memory leak when the pool is being cleaned up. That's why you should set the length back to the original value when you finished using the array.

Comment: Is there no way make it a pointer? I mean, modify only pointer values, and not affecting original one?

Comment: @eocron In theory it could be somehow possible to create an instance of `Array` that points to the data of the original `Array` instead of allocating its own memory. But that seems more complicated to me. And I don't even wanna think about how the garbage collector would react to this.

Comment: I updated my question and wrapped up your example into helper. It actually lowered GC pressure a lot!

Comment: After further testing, seems like this approach breaks CLR if invoked in parallel.

Comment: @eocron Interesting. Break how? Looks like you'll have to write your own pool, I guess?

Comment: Yeah, it just throws Fatal internal CLR error. Seems like I need some more woodoo to make it work properly. Will try some approaches and come back if I come up with something.

Answer (score 0):

Although this defeats the purpose of bucketing differing-length arrays: You could create an `ArrayPool<byte>` per size needed, that in turn limits the maximum length of the arrays to the exact target size:

```
var poolTable = new Dictionary<int, ArrayPool<byte>>();

foreach(var size in new []{ 128, 256, 512, 1024 })
{
    // Create an ArrayPool with the target size as the maximum buffer length
    poolTable.Add(size, ArrayPool<byte>.Create(size, 50));
}
```

Then when you need a reusable buffer of length `n`:

```
var buffer = poolTable[n].Rent(n);
try 
{
    // use buffer
}
finally 
{
    poolTable[n].Return(buffer, true);
}
```

Comment: It could work, but the problem is I provide ArrayPool<byte> as argument from user. Which can be anything: Shared/IO optimized/Secured etc.

Comment: The user supplies an _instance_ of the `ArrayPool<byte>`, or a type of buffer to be used?